# Problem implementing scrollTo in SwiftUI using Slider and Button

Tags: swiftui, scrollto

I'm trying to reposition a list using scrollTo with a Slider and Button and have 2 problems.  The list has Sections with id's and nested Texts below, so the scrolling (by Slider or Button) is to the Section heads only.

Here are the problems:

1. Slider works fine except that the animation briefly shows the list at the top (you can see the navigationTitle go to full size) before it scrolls to the desired position correctly.
2. The Button moves the Slider but appears to not find the id's in the Section, so it doesn't reposition to the right Section.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
struct Floors: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
struct UnitLine: Identifiable {
    let id=UUID()
    let name: String
}
 
struct UnitKeyboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var sliderValue = 8.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let floors=[Floors(id:"8",name:"8"),Floors(id:"9",name:"9"),Floors(id:"10",name:"10"),Floors(id:"11",name:"11"),Floors(id:"12",name:"12"),Floors(id:"13",name:"13"),Floors(id:"14",name:"14"),Floors(id:"15",name:"15"),Floors(id:"16",name:"16"),Floors(id:"17",name:"17"),Floors(id:"18",name:"18"),Floors(id:"19",name:"19"),Floors(id:"20",name:"20"),Floors(id:"21",name:"21"),Floors(id:"22",name:"22"),Floors(id:"23",name:"23"),Floors(id:"24",name:"24"),Floors(id:"25",name:"25"),Floors(id:"26",name:"26"),Floors(id:"27",name:"27"),Floors(id:"28",name:"28"),Floors(id:"29",name:"29")]
        let unitlines=[UnitLine(name:"01"),UnitLine(name:"02"),UnitLine(name:"03"),UnitLine(name:"04"),UnitLine(name:"05"),UnitLine(name:"06"),UnitLine(name:"07"),UnitLine(name:"08")]

        
        NavigationView {
          
            ScrollViewReader {proxy in
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    List {
                        ForEach(floors) { i in
                            Section(header: Text("Floor \(i.name)")) {
                                ForEach(unitlines) { u in
                                    Text(u.name)
                                        .padding(.trailing,200)
                                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            print("tapped")
                                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
          
                    HStack {

                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text("Flr: \(Int(sliderValue))")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(10)
                        
                        Button {
                            if sliderValue>8 {
                                   sliderValue=sliderValue-1.0
                                proxy.scrollTo(String(Int(sliderValue)), anchor: .topLeading)
                               }
                            else { print("slider below (\(sliderValue))") }
                            print(proxy)
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "minus")
                        }
                        .frame(width:30, height:15)
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        
                                            
                       Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 8...42, step: 1.0, onEditingChanged: {_ in
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(String(Int(sliderValue)), anchor: .topLeading)
                                print(String(Int(sliderValue)))
                                }
                            }
                        )
                            .background(Color.cyan)
                            .border(Color.blue, width: 1)
                            .padding(10)

                        Button {
                            if sliderValue<42 {
                                print(sliderValue)
                                sliderValue=sliderValue+1.0
                                print(sliderValue)
                                    proxy.scrollTo(String(Int(sliderValue)), anchor: .topLeading)
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                            .frame(width:30, height:15)
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(Color.gray)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Select Address")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if I hard code a value in the Button, both scrollTo and the Slider will work -- but only after clicking the button twice.  Maybe a timing problem?

Comment: I resolved the first problem by putting scrollTo in the List's onChange function and removing it from everywhere else, but I still don't understand why it always scrolls from the start of the list instead of its current position or if there is anyway to fix that.